# How do i get all the queried field values(even if they are null) in the result of javascript remoting object

Tags: visualforce, javascript-remoting

```
@RemoteAction 
    public static List<wrapLeads> searchLeads( String searchString)
    //public static String  searchLeads( String searchString)
    {
        System.debug(searchString);
        Bulk_Lead_Convert_Settings__c mc = Bulk_Lead_Convert_Settings__c.getOrgDefaults();


        System.debug('searchString ' + searchString);
        String query ='';
        if(String.isNotblank(searchString)  && String.isNotblank(mc.Api_name_of_the_field_to_be_searched__c))
        {
            String fieldsFromFieldSetCon = Cutilityfunctions.getFieldsFromFieldSet('Lead','BulkLeadConvertFields',null);

                query =  'Select ' + fieldsFromFieldSetCon + ' From Lead Where ' + mc.Api_name_of_the_field_to_be_searched__c + ' = \'' + searchString + '\'  ' ;
                //results in query like this
                //Select Id,Salutation,LastName,Company,Email,MobilePhone,Phone,Website From Lead Where company = 'Cisco'  

           system.debug(query) ;
        } 

        List<Lead> Leads = Database.query(query );  
        List<wrapLeads> lw = new List<wrapLeads>();
        for(Lead l : Leads)
        {
            lw.add(new wrapLeads(false, l));
        }
       system.debug(lw) ;

         return lw;
    }
```

The result we get has fields which only have values, the fields which have null values are not part of the result

For example if there are values for the fields mobile and website, they are not returned. I would want it to have the fieldnames and a empty string against it.

Debug statement

> 04:16:41:028 USER_DEBUG
>   [42]|DEBUG|(wrapLeads:[Leads=Lead:{Id=00Q7F000004W2SVUA0, LastName=K,
>   Company=Cisco}, checked=false],
>   wrapLeads:[Leads=Lead:{Id=00Q7F000004W2SBUA0, LastName=K,
>   Company=Cisco}, checked=false],
>   wrapLeads:[Leads=Lead:{Id=00Q7F000004W2SQUA0, LastName=K,
>   Company=Cisco}, checked=false],
>   wrapLeads:[Leads=Lead:{Id=00Q7F000004W2WhUAK, Salutation=Mr.,
>   LastName=K, Company=Cisco, Email=p@gmail.com, MobilePhone=99999999,
>   Phone=999999888, Website=www.p.com}, checked=false])

The reason is for me to show the result in a tabular format, even if its a null value i want to show it as a blank field.

I understand salesforce would be sending data in this format. Is there a way we can reformat in js or apex so we get all the field values .I would like to use it like how we use an List of Leads in the VF page.  I cant hardcode the fieldnames as i would need to pick it up from a fieldset.

Comment: One option is to return the header column's API names along with data. then you would know while iteration what to expect and what not. By that you can easily display missing fields as empty.

Comment: How would you do that?